# Map not properly applying function to list of lists

Tags: list, dictionary, scheme

I am having some trouble with using map.

I am defining binary trees as lists, and I have several functions for working with them. I am supposed to come up with several test cases and then run them. I have several trees predefined. However, to save time, I want to run the test cases as a batch with map.

For example, I have the following trees:

```
(define ctree0 '()) ;  0 nodes

(define ctree1 '("Apple" () ())) ; 1 node

(define ctree4 '("Candy" ("Artichoke" ("Apple" () ()) ()) ("Doughnut" () ()))) ; 4 nodes
```

I have the following function:

```
(define empty?
  (lambda (t)
    (null? t)
    )
  )
```

To save time, I defined a list of lists:

`(define ctrees '(ctree0 ctree1 ctree4))`

and then tried to run the following;

`(map empty? ctrees)`

which produced:

`(#f #f #f)`

The correct result should be `(#t #f #f)`, and this is what I get when I test them individually).

How can I fix this? I've tried playing with removing the front quote that supressed evaluation, but then I obviously get errors about the list being unable to evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To save time, I defined a list of lists:
>
> ```
> (define ctrees '(ctree0 ctree1 ctree4))
> ```

You didn't; you defined a list of three symbols, `ctree0`, `ctree1`, and `ctree4`. To define a list of lists, you must lose the quotes:

```
(define ctrees (list ctree0 ctree1 ctree4))
```

After this change, `(map empty? ctrees)` produces the expected result.

Comment: Perfect. I knew there was something concerning lists of lists that I wasn't understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisChambers Another way to spell this is using the backquote operator, which supports selective evaluation: `(define ctrees \`(,ctree0 ,ctree1 ,ctree4))` (note `,` preceding the symbols that need evaluation).